# How to map relations between two huge collections in AppEngine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a MOdelA which will have potentially millions entries or more and ModelB which will have probably no more then 300000 entries in the datastore.

I will be creating mostly new entries for ModelA (around 1 - 100 a second) each of the entities of ModelA will belong to one of the categories described by ModelB

I need to be able to query for all ModelA entities (sorted by creation time) that belong to one of the ModelB entities.

My problem is I'm not sure how to map the relationship. I cant Just use parent because down the road there will be MOdelC that the ModelA might belong to as well.

Any ideas wow to map it in AppEngine?

In regular SQL database I would create a pivot table mapping ModelA to ModelB and later on another pivot table mapping ModelA to ModelC. Then I could query the pivot table to give me for example all the ModelAs that belong to lets say ModelB id 5.

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

**UPDATE:**

I think the best way to explain my problem will be an example what I'm trying to do.

Lets say I have Message and City entities. Each message is posted by a User about a City (those are my ModelA and ModelB). Now Users can add as many cities as they want to their favorites.

I have to design the data model in the way that User sees Messages only about the Cities they have in favorites (sorted by date). So the example that Sean Fujiwara proposed below would not work.

I would have to to query something like this:

`db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE city IN (1, 2, 3, 4, ....)`

This cannot scale because User may have a lot of Cities added to favorites. And because in the AppEngine documentation they say:

> A single query containing not-equal or IN operators is limited to no more than 30 sub-queries.

and each IN query produces multiple == queries for each condition in the IN (...)

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in terms of a Relational database schema.  Google Datastore is a map based database, so you want to de-normalize your tables.  This pretty much means that your schema will be enforced by your application code rather than your database or model declarations.

This article explains it well:
http://highscalability.com/how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-love-using-lot-disk-space-scale

Comment: Very interesting read, thank you very much. Unfortunately it does not solve my problem. Please see the update to my question. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may have to store a list of keys, such as User.favoriteCities[City.key,City.key...].  Then you will probably have to run queries for messages 30 cities at a time.  This is a limitation, but you may be able to run multiple async requests to the db somehow to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is very simple:

```
class ModelA(db.Model):
    b = IntegerProperty()
    creation_time = DateTimeProperty(auto_add_now = True)

class ModelB(db.Model):
    category_name = StringProperty()

b_id = 5

query = db.Query(ModelA)
query.filter('b =', b_id)
query.order('creation_time')
rows = query.fetch(100)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I added the update to my question. Your example unfortunately does not solve my problem :(

Comment: I believe using the `IN` operator and multiple queries is the best way to do this with App Engine.  With the data store, everything basically needs to be precomputed sets.  On the plus side, something this simple is easy to memcache.

Comment: Unfortunately in the GAE documentation it says: A single query containing not-equal or IN operators is limited to no more than 30 sub-queries.

Meaning if the user favorites list is longer then 30 elements the query will break.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Overview

Comment: By multiple queries, I meant splitting it up into groups of 30, if those are your requirements.  e.g. `WHERE city IN (1, 2, 3, ...)` and `WHERE city IN (31, 32, 33, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an unowned bidirectional relationship. One way you could do this is to create a list of keys on each side. If you are using something like JPA, basically you'd have a ManyToMany relationship between Users and Cities. A OneToMany relationship between users and messages. And a OneToMany relationship between Cities and Messages.

So to get messages you'd basically query on the list of messages that join on your user. Then you could pull the cities out of those messages which are in your favorite cities by returning the list of your favorite cities from your user.

Datanucleus provides unowned relationships as well now too.

http://datanucleus.blogspot.com/